# MSAccess VBA sort query by ascending

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following query:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "BPRIL Data Entry", , , "[Deleted]<>-1 Or [Deleted] Is Null", acFormEdit, , ""
```

How do I sort by ascending. 
I know it's something like ORDER BY ASC but I don't know where to place it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use properties of the form once it is open:

```
Forms![BPRIL Data Entry].OrderBy = "Something"
Forms![BPRIL Data Entry].OrderByOn = True
```

Ascending is the default.